# c#: can you use a boolean predicate as the parameter to an if statement?

Tags: c#, boolean, if-statement

In C#, can you use a boolean predicate on its own as the parameter for an if statement?

eg:

```
string str = "HELLO";
if (str.Equals("HELLO"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("HELLO");
}
```

Will this code output "HELLO", or does it need to be:

```
string str = "HELLO";
if (str.Equals("HELLO") == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("HELLO");
}
```

If there is anything else wrong with the above code segments, please point it out.

EDIT: double equals as per answers

Comment: Rather than asking a question here, wouldn't it have been quicker and easier to just try these two snippets in your compiler?

Comment: I have something I believe is logically equivalent in my code but it is not executing as per the answers here.  I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Don't forget that when comparing strings, HELLO and hello are not the same - case is important.

Comment: IsEqual only checks that they are the same object because if they are equal they are the same object.  Strings in .Net are immutable and are only created once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

(Your second example needs 2 = (i.e. ==) to be correct).

Comment: This is the chosen answer because it was earliest.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the latter snippet won't even compile because it's trying to *assign* `true` to `str.Equals("Hello")` (you've got a single = instead of ==) but either:

```
if (str.Equals("HELLO"))
```

or

```
if (str.Equals("HELLO") == true)
```

will work. The latter is pretty strongly discouraged though - it's pretty ugly.

Bear in mind that string overloads ==, so you can actually write:

```
if (str == "HELLO")
```

which is somewhat simpler.

Comment: Just to expand on Jon's response a little, the if statement will operate with any expression that evaluates to a boolean result.

Comment: If I am experiencing results contrary to this answer, what could be going wrong?  Could there be an issue with string terminating characters or something else?

Comment: you could always try str.Trim() == "HELLO" to ensure any whitespace is removed from the beginning and end your string.

Answer (score 3):

The second version won't even compile, since you need `==`, not `=`.

Seeing code like `if (foo == true)` makes bile rise up into my mouth.

Comment: If `foo` is a nullable boolean, `foo == true` is a valid option.

Comment: (foo == true != false) evaluates to the same result, but your fellow developers won't invite you to their parties anymore.

Comment: Jens, I never said it was invalid.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have is correct, the `if` statement checks to see if the statement within the brackets evaluates to true.

Remember that comparisons in c# use == not = , so it should be `if (x == true)`

This can be used in other situations like:

```
bool isACat = true;

if (isACat)
{
}
```

It is good practice to put **is** or a similar identifier (Is/Has/Should/Will/Do/Must...) before boolean variable names, as it makes it easy to read when you are not using == true.

Comment: You don't always need an `is` prefix. Anything that semantically can be either "yes" or "no" is appropriate.

Comment: You don't need it, but it is a good practice, rather than have if (cat)

Comment: @SLC: I mean that there are other semantically correct identifier names that don't have an `is` prefix. For example, `hasSomeProperty`, or any verb-noun pair where the verb is in the third person simple present tense (as opposed to imperative, for method names). I suppose more complicated names only really work for object properties, though, where there's a clear subject.

Comment: @Will has is just a rephrasing of is, isFourLegged or hasFourLegs... the key point is that it should be recognisable as a boolean.

Comment: @SLC: Sure but what about something like `hasCar`? `isInPossessionOfCar`? Or what about `SomeType.AcceptsConnections`, which is `true` if objects of `SomeType` accept connections? I'm just saying that sometimes `is` isn't the appropriate verb!

Comment: @Will Yes, sometimes it isn't, all I am saying is, make sure they are instantly identifiable as boolean. In most cases, putting Is/Has/Should/Will/Do/Must/etc. in front makes it much clearer, and many programming guides recommend you do so. Compare selected with isSelected, Complete with isComplete, etc.

Comment: @SLC: I fully agree that `isSelected` is better than `selected`, I'm just talking about which verb is used as a prefix, that's all :) All of those examples you just gave are exactly what I was trying to demonstrate.

Comment: @Will then we are in agreement :)

Answer (score 2):

> can you use a boolean predicate on its own as the parameter for an if statement

Strictly speaking, the answer to *this* is 'no', because a **predicate** is a **function** (in the mathematical sense). What you *can* use for the conditional expression in an `if` is any boolean **expression**, including (as here) the **result** of the invocation of a predicate on a value.

To expand, the 'predicate' here is 'equals HELLO'. It is a function (in the mathematical sense) that operates on values of type `string`, and returns boolean values. Once you have obtained a boolean value (by applying this function to a particular string, `str`), you do not need to explicitly compare it to `true`: you can just use it.

As you will see from others' answers, code in which expressions of boolean type are explicitly compared to boolean literals will often cause code-style pain in the reader :) (My 'favourite' peeve is `<boolean expression> ? true : false`).

Comment: Isn't the isEquals() a function?

Comment: @Craig Johnston : yes, 'is equals' is a function that consumes *two* values and returns a boolean. By specifying one of those values in advance, we make a predicate, a function which consumes *one* value and returns a boolean.

Comment: Why do you say isEquals is a function that consumes two values?  It consumes only one value: the string parameter.

Comment: @Craig Johnston : no, 'equals' takes two parameters (the two items to compare for equality). 'equals HELLO' is however a *different* function, which takes only one parameter. Since it is a function that takes one parameters and returns a boolean, it is a predicate. You could call it a 'partial application' of 'equals' if you wanted to use the technical term.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong.

Just two different ways of picking up the same spoon to feed yourself ;)